# How to refresh the view when angular $http promise call wrapped in rxjs Observable

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs

I have a project that uses angular's $http service to load data from a remote location. I want to use rxjs Observables so the call in my service looks like this:

```
    userInfo() : Rx.Observable<IUserInfo> {
        var url : string = someUrl + this._accessToken;

        return Rx.Observable.fromPromise<IUserInfo>( this.$http.get<IUserInfo>( url ) );
    }
```

and this is subscribed to by my controller like this:

```
    getUserInfo() : void {
        this._googleService.userInfo().subscribe(
            ( result ) => { this.handleUserInfo( result ) },
            ( fault : string ) => this.handleError( fault )
        )
    }

    private handleUserInfo( result : IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IUserInfo> ) : void {
        console.log( "User info received at " + new Date() );

        this._name = result.data.given_name + " " + result.data.family_name;
        this._email = result.data.email;

        this._profilePicUrl = result.data.picture;
    }
```

the problem is that despite the name, email and profile pic being updated these changes are not visible. As soon as anything else triggers an angular $apply the changes appear but because of the Observable these changes in the controller happen after the angular digest loop that is triggered by the $http call.
This does work correctly if my service just returns a promise to the controller.

How do I update my view in this case? I do not want to manually have to wire up each observable to trigger a digest cycle. I want all Observables to trigger a digest cycle when they receive a new value or error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the [ScopeScheduler](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js/blob/v0.0.14/src/scopescheduler.js) from rx.angular.js for this. We only have to create a new one where we create our angular module and pass the $rootScope to it:

```
const module : ng.IModule = angular.module( 'moduleName', [] );

module.run( ["$rootScope", ( $rootScope ) => {
    new Rx.ScopeScheduler( $rootScope );
}]);
```

That's all you have to do. Now all Rx.Observables trigger an $apply when they get a new value.

For some reason the ScopeScheduler was deleted when the rx.angular.js library was upgraded to rxjs version 4. We have to use rx.angular.js version 0.0.14 to use the ScopeScheduler.

I do not know what the suggested solution to this is in version 4.

A project using this fix can be viewed here:

https://github.com/Roaders/Typescript-OAuth-SPA/tree/observable_apply_issues

Comment: I see ScopeScheduler is back, but you're still having issues with it: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js/issues/130

I have the same issue, and solve it by using `.safeApply(this.$rootScope);` on all my rx observables. This way I only have to remember to add that on every place I produce an rx observable, instead of having to do a `$scope.$apply()` in every `.subscribe()` where I consume an rx observable.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the Rx.ScopeScheduler method to work, so I just overwrote the rx observable subscribe method itself instead, and wrapped the callbacks in $rootScope.$apply :)

```
module.run(['$rootScope', 'rx', function ($rootScope, rx) {
    rx.Observable.prototype.subscribe = function (n, e, c) {
        if(typeof n === 'object') {
            return this._subscribe(n);
        }

        var onNext = function(){};
        if(n) {
            onNext = function(value) {
                if($rootScope.$$phase) {
                    n(value);
                }
                else {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function(){ n(value); });
                }
            };
        }

        var onError = function(err) { throw err; };
        if(e) {
            onError = function(error) {
                if($rootScope.$$phase) {
                    e(error);
                }
                else {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function(){ e(error); });
                }
            };
        }

        var onCompleted = function(){};
        if(c) {
            onCompleted = function() {
                if($rootScope.$$phase) {
                    c();
                }
                else {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function(){ c(); });
                }
            };
        }

        return this._subscribe(
            new rx.AnonymousObserver(onNext, onError, onCompleted)
        );
    };
}]);
```